# Makefile: How to recursively trace a program's import hierarchy?

Tags: recursion, makefile

## The problem

Consider the following recipe:

```
a: b
    <create a>
```

Maybe it's correct. But if `b` imports another program `c`,
then it's not. It should instead say this:

```
a: b c
    <create a>
```

And if `c` depends on `d`, it should say this:

```
a: b c d
    <create a>
```

And any time `c` changes what it imports,
any output that depends on `b`
needs its recipe updated in the makefile.

That's tedious. It's also dangerous,
because it's easy to miss a recipe that needed updating.

## What would be better

is to only have to say once what other source files a given source file depends on,
rather than each time it appears in any recipe's prerequisites.
That is, the Makefile should be doing the recursion, not I.

(Even better would be if I had to say zero times what the source file depends on, instead generating that information automatically from the code. I wonder if such a solution exists?)

## I have an awkward solution.

Here's a (extremely) minimal example:

https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/makefile-import-aware/

Here's the Makefile (everything else in the repo is just empty files or documentation):

```
.no_younger_than/lib/a: \
  code/lib/a
    install -D /dev/null .no_younger_than/lib/a

.no_younger_than/b: \
  code/b \
  .no_younger_than/lib/a
    install -D /dev/null .no_younger_than/b

c: .no_younger_than/b
    echo "yes" > c
```

Those `install` directives create a filetree parallel to the code,
which contains an empty "evidence" file corresponding to each source file.
The makefile creates such evidence each time it runs.
If the timestamp on an evidence file is T,
that means the file it corresponds to was not modified any later than T.

This solution does everything that I want,
but I dread having to explain it to someone else.
I'm hoping there exists prior art that's already been documented,
so I can avoid said explanation.

Comment: You can autogenerate dependencies for C/C++ with gcc. Do you have any specific language in mind?

Comment: I'm using Python and Haskell. I suspected C programmers would have this solved. "Autogenerate dependencies" is a useful handle; I see a few already-solved StackOverflow questions about that for Python. Thank you!

Comment: I guess you need a combination of this: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ and this: https://github.com/google/importlab

Comment: Why you don't simply express the real dependencies (`b: c`)?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean by _import_. Do you need to recompile anything based on changing _import_ statements?

Comment: @Vroomfondel By "an import" I mean any time one source file in my project imports another one. I'm using Python and not actually building any executables, but rather data. Each program builds a .csv file, and can depend on other .csv files as well as other programs. But yes, changing an import statement in one source file could mean I'd need to rebuild every data set that depends on it.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet maybe you're right, that that's better? I could have sworn I tried that first and it didn't rebuild under the conditions I wanted, but trying it again it seems to do everything my more complex solution does. Here's the toy example I made:

https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/makefile-import-aware/blob/55b285f645d6b336183988db9917816f8883a173/maybe-equally-good/Makefile

Comment: @JeffreyBenjaminBrown I looked at your toy example and it looks much better to me. It is 100% in line with the make principles.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Cool, thanks! But still it seems to me a little awkward (albeit less so): If the `b.py` source file is not found, the Makefile will go ahead and create it. Of course the user will find out quickly if it's an empty file. But it would be more natural to check for existence, and only touch the file if it already exists, otherwise throwing a not-found error. On the other hand that would make each of the verify-existence recipes a lot longer; maybe not worth it.

Comment: @JeffreyBenjaminBrown You could use a recipe like `[ -f $@ ] && touch $@` which is not much more complex. Moreover, you could assign it to a make variable (`FOO = [ -f $@ ] && touch $@`) and use the variable in your recipes.